# Django Haystack : Add data from prepared_field_name to the Indexing template

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am using templates to create the document which will be indexed, my template looks like, say:

```
{{object.generic_data}}
```

Now, i want my generic_data to be generated by a prepare_generic_data function . Doing this doesn't seem to work as the data is being fed to the template before the prepare function can return it seems.

So, I wanted to know if there is some way for me to use the template along side the prepare function or another way to get around this problem.

Also, please let me know if the question isn't clear enough.
Edit:

Search_index

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from diskus.models import Recipe,Post


class PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    post_id=indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='user_entity_id_id')
    content_key=indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='content_key')
    content_type=indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='content_type')
    generic_data=indexes.CharField()
    slug=indexes.CharField(model_attr='slug')

    def get_model(self):
        return Post

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()

    def prepare_generic_data(self,obj):
        if obj.content_type==3:
            recipe=Recipe.objects.get(pk=obj.content_key)
            return recipe.name
        else:
            return "random_stuff"
```

Model:

```
class Post(UserEntity):
    user_entity_id = models.OneToOneField(UserEntity,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name='post',
                              primary_key=True,
                              db_column='id')
    content_key = models.IntegerField()
    content_type = models.IntegerField()

class Recipe(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve? If you have a template where you can generate arbitrary content, why do you need a prepare function as well?

Comment: @solarissmoke in the prepare_generic_data i am getting data from another model ( using model.objects.get(pk=content_key)) and content_key is defined  as content_key=indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='content_key')  ,

Comment: Can you post all your code as an edit to the question? Also post the model and index class as well.

Comment: @solarissmoke its a big code base , so i posted the models and search index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of an indexing template `object` is the *model instance* (a `Post` object), not a `PostIndex` object. So `object` has no `generic_data` property. You cannot access other index fields from inside the template.

The simplest solution is to move the logic for `generic_data` into the `Post` model like so:

```
class Post(UserEntity):

    def generic_data(self):
        if self.content_type == 3:
            # NOTE: you may need to ensure the Recipe is defined 
            # before Post in the models.py file, or you will get a name
            # resolution error.
            recipe = Recipe.objects.get(pk=self.content_key)
            return recipe.name
        else:
            return "random_stuff"
```

Then the existing code in your template will work:

```
{{ object.generic_data }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a template here, you should use the [prepare](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/searchindex_api.html#prepare-self-object) or [prepare_FOO](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/searchindex_api.html#prepare-foo-self-object) methods:

```
class PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    # text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True)
    post_id = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='user_entity_id_id')
    content_key = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='content_key')
    content_type = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='content_type')
    # generic_data = indexes.CharField()
    slug = indexes.CharField(model_attr='slug')

    def get_model(self):
        return Post

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()

    def prepare(self, obj):
        prepared_data = super().prepare(obj)
        prepared_data["text"] = "random_stuff"
        if obj.content_type == 3:
            recipe = Recipe.objects.get(pk=obj.content_key)
            prepared_data["text"] = recipe.name

        return prepared_data
```

Here is an example using the `prepare_FOO` method:

```
class PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    # text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True)
    post_id = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='user_entity_id_id')
    content_key = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='content_key')
    content_type = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='content_type')
    # generic_data = indexes.CharField()
    slug = indexes.CharField(model_attr='slug')

    def get_model(self):
        return Post

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()

    def prepare_text(self, obj):
        if obj.content_type == 3:
            recipe = Recipe.objects.get(pk=obj.content_key)
            return recipe.name

        return "random_stuff"
```